# Image Pixel firing on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We tried firing the image pixel on submit button where we have form submission plus 1x1 pixel firing but either of them works.

Please help sort me the below:

```
<script>
function downloadpixel() {
    document.getElementById("btnSave").innerHTML = "www.bizographics.com/collect/?fmt=gif&url=mobility.microsoft.com&pid=78";
}
</script>

<input type="image" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" src="/india/campaign/office365/images/download1.png" onclick="downloadpixel(); return submitData('.form');" style="border-width:0px;cursor: hand;" />
```

With the above code, the form submission is working but not the pixel i am trying to fire.

Let me know if further detail is required from my end

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
document.getElementById("btnSave").innerHTML = '<img src="www.bizographics.com/collect/?fmt=gif&url=mobility.microsoft.com&pid=78">';
```

*Be careful since the submit page refresh can cancel the image request.

Comment: I think document.getElementById("btnSave").innerHTML will always have empty string. You can add another line below this to check like alert(document.getElementById("btnSave").innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

You can try jquery also like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnkr4hx8/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btnSave").click(function(){
 alert("hrl");
document.getElementById("btnSave").src = "www.bizographics.com/collect/?fmt=gif&url=mobility.microsoft.com&pid=78";
   });
});
```

hope this helps :)